# How to preprocess data to generate barplots in R

Tags: r, plot

I want to generate (grouped and stacked) bar plots from values I have in lists:

```
dog = list(a=100, c=30, t=140, g=102)
cat = list(a=99,  c=31, t=150, g=123)
pig = list(a=100, c=12, t=90,  g=144)
```

In the first barplot, the data should be groupe by the letter (ACTG) and each animal should have it's own bar.

The second barplot should be a stacked plot that that shows for each animal the percentage of `a`, `c`, `t` and `g`.

In `help(barplot)` I read, that I need to generate a Matrix-like datastructure. What is a preferred way to put the data into a `matrix`?

In an example I also saw, that people use `?tables` that already have the names in it. What is the difference between a table an a matrix, and how can I generate a table from my data?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to combine your data into a matrix:

```
temp <- do.call(cbind, lapply(list(dog = dog, cat = cat, pig = pig), unlist))
temp
#   dog cat pig
# a 100  99 100
# c  30  31  12
# t 140 150  90
# g 102 123 144
str(temp)
#  num [1:4, 1:3] 100 30 140 102 99 31 150 123 100 12 ...
#  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#   ..$ : chr [1:4] "a" "c" "t" "g"
#   ..$ : chr [1:3] "dog" "cat" "pig"
is.matrix(temp)
# [1] TRUE
```

Use `rbind` or transpose (`t`) the data if you wanted the animals as the rows.

---

From there, plotting is simple:

```
# Grouped by ACGT, each animal own bar
barplot(t(temp), beside = TRUE)
```

[image]

```
# Stacked bar plot
barplot(prop.table(temp, margin = 2))
```

[image]

The exercise of adding legends, titles, and so on will be left to the reader :)

---

`table` *is* a `matrix`, but I don't think it is what you are looking for here with your data. Generally, the `table` function is used to tabulate frequencies.

Here is a basic example:

```
set.seed(1)
mydf <- data.frame(A = sample(letters[1:4], 20, replace = TRUE),
           B = sample(c("red", "green", "blue"), 20, replace = TRUE))
mytable <- table(mydf)
mytable
#    B
# A   blue green red
#   a    0     3   1
#   b    3     0   2
#   c    2     3   0
#   d    1     2   3
is.matrix(mytable)
# [1] TRUE
```

The `barplot` function will directly accept this as input.

---

Finally, a quick way to convert your data to a "long" `data.frame` (which is useful, as demonstrated by @mOnhawk not just for plotting with `ggplot2`, but also for `lattice`) is to use something like the following:

```
temp <- stack(data.frame(dog = dog, cat = cat, pig = pig))
temp1 <- cbind(temp[-2], do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(temp$ind), "\\.")))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `matrix` with:

```
data <- matrix(c(dog, cat, pig), nrow=3, ncol=4, dimnames=list(c("dog", "cat", "pig"), c("A", "C", "T", "G")))
data

>   dog cat pig
> A 100 99  100
> C 30  31  12 
> T 140 150 90 
> G 102 123 144
```

Plot:

```
barplot(data)
```

And the result:

[image]

```
x <- data.frame(
     animals=c(rep("dog",4),rep("cat",4),rep("pig",4)),
     gen=c(rep(c("A","C","T","G"),3)),
     value=c(100,30,140,102,99,31,150,123,100,12,90,144))

>    animals gen value
> 1      dog   A   100
> 2      dog   C    30
> 3      dog   T   140
> 4      dog   G   102
> 5      cat   A    99
> 6      cat   C    31
> 7      cat   T   150
> 8      cat   G   123
> 9      pig   A   100
> 10     pig   C    12
> 11     pig   T    90
> 12     pig   G   144
```

With the help of:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

ggplot(mx, aes(x=animals,y=value)) + 
     geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
     facet_grid(~gen)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Just FYI, the way you've created the matrix in the first step actually creates a `list` of vectors of length 1. Use `c(data)` to see what I mean. I had the same problem with my initial solution, so I just thought I would pass the information along!